# Cherrypy web Application is not visible on internet but able to access on the local system

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, cherrypy

I have developed an web application using Cherrypy in AWS EC2,When running this application I can see it in the local web browser using localhost but using the system IP address I am unable to access the site.Can any one guide me how to host a application so that it can be accessible on internet outside AWS EC2 machine.

I used below configuration.

```
[global]
server.socket_host : '0.0.0.0'
server.socket_port: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help !

When I am troubleshooting the issue further I found the ip is pingable but the  port 80 is not working.
This is due to windows advanced firewall settings which is blocking it.
I have created a new inbound rule in windows advanced fire wall setting to allow the 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Security Group attached to your EC2 instance to open port 80:

[image]

Comment: I tried by changing this setting too,it is not working.Any other suggestions please.  I have a elastic IP too for AWS.

Comment: @Vineel Which Operating System is your EC2 instance using?